# XP-Pen Software doesn't detect tablet when connected via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, tablet, graphics-tablet

I have a XP-Pen Deco MW connected to my computer via bluetooth. I have installed the pentablet software from the [manufacture's website](https://www.xp-pen.com/download-846.html). Now, if I start the pentablet app, it tells me that I need to connect the device. It already is connected, though. I can also move the mouse using it. I just cannot change any settings as the app does not find the tablet.

I can work around it by connecting the tablet using a cable, but I would need to use the cable all the time as otherwise the settings wouldn't stay applied.

Here's my xinput. First one is using bluetooth, second one is while connected via cable:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ XP-PEN MOUSE                              id=24   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Deco MW Mouse                             id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Deco MW Pen (0)                           id=28   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ XP-PEN ERASER                             id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ XP-PEN STYLUS                             id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Deco MW Keyboard                          id=26   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Deco MW                                   id=27   [slave  keyboard (3)]

$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ XP-PEN MOUSE                              id=24   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Hanvon Ugee Deco MW Mouse                 id=26   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ XP-PEN STYLUS Pen (0)                     id=28   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ XP-PEN ERASER                             id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ XP-PEN STYLUS                             id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Hanvon Ugee Deco MW Keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Hanvon Ugee Deco MW                       id=27   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: i have the same problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the XP-Pen support and they answered that they basically don't support bluetooth on linux.

> sincerely sorry to inform you of that it cant work via Bluetooth on
> Linux. So you can only use the USB cable to connect this tablet to
> your Linux computer when you are using it on Linux. Thank you for your
> understanding!